# android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout isn't working in android library project

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I create my own library with custom component in android. Component is very simple:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:baselineAligned="true"/>

            <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtExample"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/simpleText"/>

 </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

When i put it into android project it is working, but when i try this with custom component library it is not working. In debug i see that TextInputLayout haven't got a android.R.attr.state_focused when i click into EditText. It's a bug for TextInputLayout?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in android support library. i notify google.

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others